# Ubuntu 16.04.3 - R9 380X Black screen at install

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a Sapphire R9 380X and i tried to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 but when i press Install Ubuntu on GRUB the screen turns off and the fans spin at maximum speed and i cant get into the installer. In Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Kernel 4.8 it was working fine. I saw at AMD  that they have released a new driver for Kernel 4.10 but i was using the out of the box driver that ubuntu used "amdgpu". Why it isnt working now?

Comment: This isnt my problem...even after i update ubuntu i still get the black screen. Also even if i install amdgpu-pro driver same thing happens.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you try, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))